# Just numbers from file

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter file name");
String fileName = sc.next();
String line;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
while(s.hasNextLine()){
    line = s.next();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

The file looks like this

```
---------------
   aaaa   bbb
//another comment
// a d 3 5

2 4 6 
2 a 6
10 10

30 20
nbnb
------------
```

And I want it to print out the numbers in each line
Example:

```
 2 4 6
 2 6
 10 10
 30 20
```

It prints out each number including the numbers in the comment.  It also prints one number on each line.  I want it to print like in the example and also skip the comments.

Comment: Could you post the contents of your file too?

Comment: I see you changed your code to have backslashes in the regex. Did that make any difference? Was it an error in typing code into the website (you no have copy-paste?)

Comment: @Floris No I didn't copy and paste. I just typed it in wrong. It displays the numbers but doesn't ignore the comments

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you meant to use backslashes:

```
Pattern p = pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

since the expression you wrote:

```
"//d+"
```

looks for two forward slashes followed by at least one instance of the letter `d`...

The following code seems to behave in the way you wanted:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
String s[]={"some text 123 and 234 some 456 numbers", "just text", "123 234"};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
for(String ss: s) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ss);
    int flag = 0;
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
        flag = 1;
        }
    if(flag == 1) System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
123 234 456 
123 234
```

Note - don't use `println()` for each number as it will generate a newline. Instead, I set a flag before the `while` loop; if I leave the loop and the flag is set, it means there were numbers in the string, and I need a newline (`System.out.println();`). Otherwise, no need for a newline (so a text only line doesn't result in an empty space).

I was using an online Java compiler so couldn't test the file I/O part of your code - but I think this should help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one line:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\D+", " ").trim());
```

This replaces all sequences of non-digits with a space (and removes whitespace from the ends).